# Difference between pg8000 and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pg8000

Can anyone please help me on finding the advantage of pg8000 over SQLAlchemy?
We are using Python to connect to postgresql and sometimes to Google Firebase.

So, which will be helpful for interaction and better performance.

-Srivathsava

Comment: SQLAlchemy is an ORM, among other things, while pg8000 is a DB-API driver for talking to PostgreSQL. The latter can be used by the former.